# Permit any user to mount any CIFS share

Tags: ubuntu, mount, cifs

Essentially, I want the Ubuntu pre-10.10 behaviour back. The setuid method ([see notes](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html#id2532813)) does not work anymore. I search a lot on the Internet, but I haven't found a satisfying solution.

I have read a solution that involves editing the sudoers file (`ALL ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/mount.cifs`). But then, the users would also be able to specify a directory as a mount-point they normally would not have access to, right? This is not what I want.